# apex:outputText does not display the unit of my field

Tags: visualforce

I use an `apex:outputText` for displaying a field, that is a percentage, like this :

```
<apex:outputText value="{!Opportunite_custom__c.ME_taux__c}" />
```

The problem is that it does not display the result with the symbol '%' lieke that :

> 55%

but only

> 55

(When I use an `apex:pageBlockTable` tag I can see the % symbol, but in this case I can't use this tag.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because the `<apex:outputText>` tag will only display the text as a standard output, it does no formatting of any kind.

If you want it to auto-render dependant on the field type you need to use the `<apex:outputField>` tag, this tag works out what field type it is and will append/prepend any relevant data needed.

This works with Currency fields, Percentage fields, Decimal fields, the works!

It even auto generates Picklist values if the specific field is a Picklist, so you don't need to :)

Comment: Looks like you missed the tag you recommend using!

Comment: Ahhhh sugar! I put the brackets in so it's trying to render those -_- use "apex:outputField" that will do the magic mentioned above :) Updated the above as well

Answer (score 0):

```
<apex:outputText>
```

always show text data, not a percentage so to see % symbol you have to add it at the end.

```
<apex:outputText value="{!Opportunite_custom__c.ME_taux__c}%">
```

Thanks